# Como pausar o chronometer e continuar de onde parou?

Tags: java, android

No Android possui a *view* `Chronometer`, que inicializa automaticamente quando entra na *ativity*.

Para reiniciar o cronometro a partir do `0` uso o seguinte código:

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
chronometer.start();
```

Quando utilizo o `stop()`, ele pára **visualmente** de cronometrar, porém quando é pressionado novamente o `start()` é como se não tivesse parado o cronometro, pois na verdade estava funcionando em background.

Como faço para pausar o `chronometer` e continuar de onde parou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O valor apresentado pelo cronometro é calculado pela diferença entre o instante actual(`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`) e o valor de referência - aquele que foi "setado" através de `setBase()`.
É por isso que quando volta a chamar `start()` o cronometro se comporta como não tivesse sido parado.

Para obter o efeito que pretende tem de ajustar o valor de referência de forma a que a diferença entre o instante actual e ele seja igual ao valor apresentado pelo cronometro na altura em que foi parado.

Guarde o instante em que parou o cronometro:

```
chronometer.stop();
stopTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Antes de fazer `start()` recalcule o valor base de forma a incluir o tempo que esteve parado:

```
long pauseDuration = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stopTime;
chronometer.setBase(chronometer.getBase() + pauseDuration);
chronometer.start();
```

Comment: Revisei somente hoje! Havia feito algo muito parecido, usando a mesma lógica. Funcionou perfeito. Abs;